# How to set basefont color?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to change my basefont color.

I used a rectangle to set the background color, but I can't figure out how to get my font to be white, as I'm using PdfContentByte object.

I tried to use Chunk to set the font color but SetFontAndSize overrides it.

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);

iTextSharp.text.Font titreProgFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times", 12, BaseColor.WHITE);

string nomProgramme, codeProgramme;
nomProgramme = "PROGRAMMEUR ANALYSTE";
codeProgramme = "LEA.1A";

Chunk titreProgChunk = new Chunk(nomProgramme + " (" + codeProgramme + ")", titreProgFont);

PdfContentByte cb2 = writer.DirectContent;
cb2.SaveState();
cb2.SetColorFill(BaseColor.GRAY);
cb2.Rectangle(200, 200, 200, 200);
cb2.Fill();
cb2.RestoreState();
cb2.BeginText();
cb2.SetFontAndSize(bfTimes, 12);
cb2.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, titreProgChunk.ToString(), 200, 200, 0);
cb2.EndText();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use one of the fill colors to change the font color such as `cb2.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);`

Comment: Thanks, I thought SetColorFill could be only used to fill rectangles or backgrounds...